# problema al instalar en ubuntu un servicio

Tags: visual-studio, linux, ubuntu, consola, ssh

Buenas tardes amigos estoy comenzando usar la consola (Sistema operativo ubuntu 16.04) y estaría necesitando instalar este servicio, supuestamente este es el comando:

```
sudo ‘/home/exemys/Desktop/MW-XF/mwxf.in’ install
```

lo descargue y descomprimí en /home/MW-XF

pero al ejecutar el comando no instala el servicio alguien me podría orientar cual es el comando que debo aplicar?

```
sudo ‘/home/MW-XF/mwxf.in’ install
```

Comment: Las aplicaciones se instalan, los servicios se inician, detienen o se ve su status, para instalar una aplicación **sudo apt-get install nombre_aplicacion** , para ver el estado de un servicio **sudo service servicio status** , para detener un servicio **sudo service servicio stop** , para iniciar un servicio **sudo service servicio start**

Comment: @RobertoPaillao, pero en este caso es un servicio que debo instalar porque es de un tercero entonces no viene predefinido, eso es lo que no se como intalarlo

Comment: Pero, una consulta: ¿Estas tratando de instalar MiddleWare?, si es así, estuve viendo en su web y no corre en Linux , solo Windows.

Comment: @RobertoPaillao, eso es correcto estoy tratando de instalar el MW, pero ellos tienen una version para ubuntu pero ni idea que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 0):

El MW (Middleware) de [Exemys](https://www.exemys.com/beta/docs/spanish/CLAN_UM/MW.html) sólo se puede instalar en plataformas Windows, al menos eso detallan en su sitio web:

`...el MW se puede instalar sobre plataformas Windows 2003, XP, Vista (de 32 bits), 2008, 7, 8 y 10 (de 32 o 64 bits). Para que funcione, el MW debe tener instalado el Java Runtime Environment de 32 bits versión 1.8 o superior`

Comment: ellos sacaron una version que corre en ubuntu pero me tranqué tratando de instalarlo, como no conozco linux no tengo ideo que estoy haciendo mal